# conditional operator usage in the below code

Tags: java

I was using the conditional operator as shown below..

```
String AccessType = (a.isActive() && b.isActive() ? "Active" : "NotActive");
```

Now I want that if a.active is true and b.active is also true then the result should be Active but if initially a.active fails then npo need to test b.isactive just print Not active now please advise does  my above implementation is correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is already correct. The "laziness" aspect (only calling `b.isActive()` if `a.isActive()` returns true) is taken care of by the behaviour of the `&&` operator, which is *short-circuiting*.

From [section 15.23 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

The fact that you're using this as the condition (first operand) of the conditional operator is irrelevant. So your code is equivalent to:

```
boolean active = a.isActive() && b.isActive();
String AccessType = (active ? "Active" : "NotActive");
```

I would make two changes to your code though:

- I wouldn't use the brackets. They're unnecessary. You're not calling a method - it's just a conditional operator.
- I'd rename the variable to `accessType`. Java naming conventions use `camelCase` for variables.

So:

```
String accessType = a.isActive() && b.isActive() ? "Active" : "NotActive";
```

Comment: +1, your explanation is as usual good and indicating the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [condional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

```
   boolean isAActive = a.isActive();
   boolean isBActive = b.isActive();
   String AccessType = (isAActive && isBActive) ? "Active" : "NotActive";
```

instead of

```
String AccessType = (a.isActive() && b.isActive() ? "Active" : "NotActive");
```

use the conditions with in the bracket

Comment: You don't need a bracket at the end of the condition.

Comment: There's no problem here to start with. The original code was already fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of readability, you could to wrap the condition

```
a.isActive() && b.isActive()
```

in circular brackets `()`:

```
(a.isActive() && b.isActive())
```

Also there is no need of bracket at the end. So your final condition should look like:

```
(a.isActive() && b.isActive()) ? "Active" : "NotActive";
```

As the brackets are optional so the condition can be re-written as:

```
a.isActive() && b.isActive() ? "Active" : "NotActive";
```

Comment: Thanks juned so this will work for both the cases that is if a.active is true and b.active is also true then Active will be printed and if initially a.active fails then directly it will print notactive.

Comment: @tuntunwretee yes it will return "Active" only in case when both a.isActive and b.isctive are true.

Comment: yeah agree but i want that if initially A.isactive fails then it should not go the check b.active it should directly print NotActive, will it do the same

Comment: @tuntunwretee This is how && operator work in java and most of other languages. If the first conditions fails, no other condition is checked.

Comment: There's no need to use brackets at all. `&&` has higher precedence than the `?` of the conditional operator.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i understand that, but brackets adds more readability and makes it easy to understand. I should have added that it is optional but added now. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, "need" is definitely incorrect. "Could" perhaps - although personally I wouldn't bother. If I felt it too hard to read in its original form, I'd extract the value in a separate local variable. But really, it's far from a complicated condition.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your inputs, appreciated! Changed the 'need' to 'could' as it is more appropriate. Bracket usage i personally liked when i started to program to avoid any errors. I believe you have explained it well in your answer. So im keeping my foolishness in my answer if it a makes sense to someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Now I want that if a.active is true and b.active is also true then
    the result should be Active
```

boolean status = a.isActive() && b.isActive();
  String value = status ? "Active" : "Inactive";

```
2. if initially a.active fails then no need to test b.isactive
```

Java follows [Short circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) So you no need to care about that java will automatically do that

Comment: No need to put it in brackets. Why did you think that's required?